# Algoritmo de Ordenación MergeSort

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con el algoritmo de ordenación MergeSort que he implementado y es que no funciona correctamente a la hora de hacer las divisiones de los parametros en la función de fusionar.

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaría muy agradecido!!

Dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void OrdenacionMergeSort(int *VectorEntrada, int Base, int Tope);
void Fusionar (int *VectorEntrada, int Base, int TopeVector1, int BaseVector2, int Tope);

int main (void)
{
    int VectorEntrada[] = {2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9}; // Vector desordenado

    int N = sizeof(VectorEntrada)/sizeof(*VectorEntrada);

    int i;
    int Base = 0;
    int Tope = N - 1;

    puts("+--------------------------+");
    puts("+ EL VECTOR SIN ORDENAR ES +");
    puts("+--------------------------+\n");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",VectorEntrada[i]);
    }

    OrdenacionMergeSort(VectorEntrada, Base, Tope);

    puts("+----------------------------------+");
    puts("+ EL VECTOR ORDENADO POR MERGESORT +");
    puts("+----------------------------------+\n");

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",VectorEntrada[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void OrdenacionMergeSort(int *VectorEntrada, int Base, int Tope)
{ 
   // Entrada: VectorEntrada[N], Base(0), Tope(N-1)

    int i, Mitad, MitadMasUno;

    if (Base < Tope)
    {
        Mitad = ((Base + Tope) / 2);
        MitadMasUno = (((Base + Tope) / 2) + 1);

        OrdenacionMergeSort(VectorEntrada, Base, Mitad);
        OrdenacionMergeSort(VectorEntrada, MitadMasUno, Tope);
        Fusionar(VectorEntrada, Base, Mitad, MitadMasUno, Tope);
    }   
}
void Fusionar (int *VectorEntrada, int Base, int TopeVector1, int BaseVector2, int Tope)
{// El tiempo para fusionar dos vectores ordenador es linal (n-1 comparaciones) -> O(n)

    int i, j;
    int indA = 0;
    int indB = 0;
    int indT = Base;
    int dimA = TopeVector1 - Base + 1;
    int dimB = Tope - BaseVector2 + 1;

    int A[dimA];
    int B[dimB];

    /* PASO 1 */

    for(i = 0; i < dimA; i++) // Copiamos cada subvector a una Var.Local
        A[i] = VectorEntrada[i];

    for(i = 0, j = BaseVector2; i < dimB; i++,j++) /* PASO 1 */
        B[i] = VectorEntrada[j];

    /* PASO 2 */

    while(indA < dimA && indB < dimB) 
     // Comparar elemento a elemento de ambos subvectores empezando
    //  Por los primeros (más pequeños) y MIENTRAS SE CUMPLA EL BUCLE...
        {
            if (A[indA] <= B[indB]) //Si elemto. A más peq. se sitúa en V.E. y avanza en A
                {
                    VectorEntrada[indT] = A[indA];
                    indA++;
                }
            else  //Si elemto. B más peq. se sitúa en V.E. y avanza en B
                {
                    VectorEntrada[indT] = B[indB];
                    indB++;
                }

            indT++; // Se avanza en T para situar el siguiente elemto. ordenado
        }

    /* PASO 3 */

    if (indA > dimA)// Si acaba el bucle porque no hay más elemtos. en B añadir elemtos. de A
    {
        for(i = indT, j = 0; i <= Tope; i++, j++)
            VectorEntrada[i] = B[j];
    }


    /* PASO 4 */

    else// Si acaba el bucle porque no hay más elemtos. en A añadir elemtos. de B
    {
        for(i = indT, j = 0; i <= Tope; i++, j++)
            VectorEntrada[i] = A[j];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Deberías de pasarte por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), y depues mejorar tu pregunta; a simple vista, [no se aprecia ningún esfuerzo en depurar el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872/), y [un exceso de código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2879). Un saludo.

Comment: Los sub-vectores `int A[dimA]` y `int B[dimB]` están mal declarados, no puedes declarar vectores de tamaño estático con variables. Aparte de eso ¿cuál es el problema que tienes? No lo has dicho.